# How do you find the specific element that is clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference, click

My school has disabled the inspect element, and the element that I want to reference isn't in the source code because it is generated later. I can use chrome bookmarks to execute javascript code, but I don't have the element's path to reference. How could I make something in js that gets the path of the element I click?

Comment: You could attach a click event listener to the global window object and log the target: `window.addEventListener("click", (event) => console.log(event.target));`

Comment: it doesn't give me the javascript path I can use to reference it, it just tells me the object, is there a way to get something you could reference in something like a queryselector?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "path" to reference it. Getting the target of the click (you don't have to just log it, you could assign it to a variable, say) means you can operate on that element - you can find out it's ID, its innerHTML, any classes assigned, you can add event listeners to it, etc. etc. What more do you need, am I missing something?

Comment: oooooookaaaaay, I get it, I was making it an alert, so it just said "[object]" or something like that, thx